# Как определить аутентифицированного пользователя в конструкторе контроллера Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Нашел в документации, что начиная с версии 5.3 нельзя использовать фасад `Auth` для получения аутентифицированного пользователя в конструкторе контроллера, а только с помощью посредника на основе `Closure`. Но как это сделать? Покажите на примере. Нижеприведённых код выдает ошибку что объект `$user` не существует:

```
public function __construct(){ 
    $this->user=auth()->user();
}

public function getuser(){ 
    $user=this->user;
    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации к версии 5.3 у них же пример этот был, чтобы поулчить доступ к сессиям нужно обратиться к middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

В вашем случае получается нужно сделать следующее:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему так?

Comment: Потому что нет доступа к сессиям у конструктора, чтобы его получить нужно "вклиниться" в цикл обработки middleware и там уже добавить.

Comment: А вот почему раньше был, а теперь нет после версии 5.3?

Comment: При миграции на 5.3 они это написали и дальше уже так нужно делать по дефольу, но в доке сейчас это не описано.